# Exponential mixing for subshifts

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite graph with adjacency matrix $A$. Let us consider the associated subshift of finite type
$$
\Sigma_A=\{(v_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} : A_{v_iv_{i+1}}>0, i\in\mathbb{Z}\}\subset V^{\mathbb{Z}}.
$$
For a stochastic matrix $P$ agreed with $A$ (that is $p_{ij}>0$ iff $a_{ij}>0$), there is a shift-invariant probability measure $\mu$ on $\Sigma_A$. Is is well-known that the dynamical system $(\Sigma_A,\sigma,\mu)$ is strongly mixing, i.e., for all measurable $B,C\subset\Sigma_A$,
$$
\mu(\sigma^nB\cap C)\rightarrow\mu(B)\mu(C), \ n\rightarrow\infty,
$$
if and only if the graph $G$ is strongly connected and aperiodic.

I am wondering if it is possible to estimate the speed of convergence. The standard proof given in textbooks uses iterations of $P$ to prove mixing for cylindrical sets. Hence one can estimate the speed of convergence for cylindrical sets in terms of the eigenvalues of $P$. Does it hold for any measurable sets? Is it always exponential, where the exponent comes from the eigenvalues of $P$?